# No display while plotting wind using barbs on basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

My dataset is in the form of a tabular data. I'm trying to plot wind data measured along a specific path by an instrument whose values and coordinates are given in this tabular data. The data header is following:

```
df.head()
>>Lat    Lon      Wind_direction    Air_temp    Water_temp  Wind_speed      
64.1513 -21.935475           106       11.13    11.98        4.8        
64.1515 -21.935418           114       11.59    11.09        9.8        
64.1596 -21.931857           114       11.78    11.58        10.8
64.1596 -21.931857           116       11.59    11.78        10.2   
64.1596 -21.931860           120       11.60    11.82        9.5
```

I'm trying to follow the example [of basemap-rotate vectors](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#rotate-vector) to plot my data but the plot is not generating any barbs and gives a blank plot. Here is my code:

```
lats1, lons1 = np.array(df.Lat), np.array(df.Lon)
# creating a grid of data points
lats2, lons2 = np.meshgrid(lons1, lats1)
# N-S and E-W components of velocity
u = np.array(df['Wind_speed'] * np.sin(df['Wind_direction'] * np.pi / 180.0))
v = np.array(df['Wind_speed'] * np.cos(df['Wind_direction'] * np.pi / 180.0))
# We have to bring u and v also in the shape of lon and lat to be able to plot them??
u2 = np.ones(lons2.shape) * u
v2 = np.ones(lons2.shape) * v

#rotating the wind vectors
u2_rot, v2_rot, x2, y2 = map.rotate_vector(u2, v2, lons2, lats2, returnxy=True)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,15), dpi=100)
# generating the map
m = Basemap(projection='lcc', resolution='l', llcrnrlat=63, 
urcrnrlat=68,llcrnrlon=-30, urcrnrlon=-20, lat_0=65.25, lon_0=-29.2)
# plotting barbs
# zorder used so that continents don't overlay barbs
m.barbs(x2, y2, u2_rot, v2_rot, pivot='middle', barbcolor='#ff7777', zorder=100)
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color="#DDEEFF")
m.drawcoastlines()
```

All I get are continents and coastlines in the map. Please point out what conceptual mistake I'm making while plotting them.

Comment: What are `u` and `v` in your example? I mean what are their values.

Comment: @ThomasKühn Thanks for pointing out. They are N-S and E-W components of velocity. I have edited the question to include that.

Comment: Well this is funny, when I change the order of `lons` and `lats` in `rotate_vector`, i.e. `map.rotate_vector(uin, vin, lats, lons, returnxy = True)`, I get barbs. However, your data sample is quite small, so you have to decide yourself whether they are in the right place. Also, you don't need `meshgrid` here at all. `barbs` can deal with 1d vectors, which is what you really want to use, so stick to `lats1`, `lons1`, `u`, and `v`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. I guess "return xy" was not returing the right values? I plotted with what you suggested using m.barbs(lons1,lats1 , u2_rot, v2_rot, pivot='middle', zorder=100, latlon=True) and it worked. However, I'm now confused as to when I need to generate a meshgrid as the example I pointed out is using meshgrid and then generating a 2-D vector for u and v components of velocity.

Comment: You would generate a meshgrid if you have 2d Data. If I understand you correctly, you have data along a given path which (presumably?) is given as a 1d vector (in the example you linked, they plot a grid of barbs). As all these methods (barb, quiver, etc.) work both with 1d and 2d vectors, you would just be easier off with not generating a meshgrid. What would 2d data even mean in your case?